# Set time for one tick mark in cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

Is there a way to set how much time one tick mark on the time line in Cesium is equal to?  I know viewer.timeline.zoomTo() sets the time range for the whole timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no public API for this, but if you're OK with a little hacking, you can find this answer in local variable `tinyTic` in [Timeline.js around line 490](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.21/Source/Widgets/Timeline/Timeline.js#L490).  The line I've identified here is just a blank line between two sections of code: the code above this line is the last bit of logic to modify `tinyTic` (possibly resetting it to `minSize` on [line 485](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.21/Source/Widgets/Timeline/Timeline.js#L485)), and then on [line 493](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.21/Source/Widgets/Timeline/Timeline.js#L493) you can see `tic = getNextTic(tic, tinyTic)` being used to generate the smallest tics.

You could, for example, add a line of code on [L490](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.21/Source/Widgets/Timeline/Timeline.js#L490) that saves the value of `tinyTic` to some object that you can access from outside code.  The value here is measured in seconds (so `5` means 5 seconds, `300` means 5 minutes, etc).